# OctoberCMS columns.yaml VALUE FROM with multiple fields

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins, october-partial

I have created one plugin using **Builder** plugin in **OctoberCMS** and in which I have **columns.yaml** file.

In a field called `property_id`, I have a field as **VALUE FROM** which is asking to add my table's field name hence I have added one called as `street_number`.

But I want to concat multiple fields there. Something like below.

```
CONCAT(street_number, ' ', address)
```

But this is not working. I have also tried with other ways but its still not working.

Can someone guide me how to accomplish this ?

Additionally, It will be great if these fields gets concat if their respective values exists in table.

This is how my **columns.yaml** file looks like.

```
columns:
    property_id:
        label: Property
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: false
        relation: Property
        valueFrom: street_number
    start_datetime:
        label: 'Start Date Time'
        type: datetime
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
    end_datetime:
        label: 'End Date Time'
        type: datetime
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
    status:
        label: Status
        type: number
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
        select: 'CASE WHEN (status =  ''1'' ) THEN ''Active'' ELSE ''Inactive'' END'
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you privide the exact code in your columns.yaml file (only for that field)?

Comment: @dragontree Up here, in my columns.yaml, I have a relation with other model as well.

Comment: @dragontree can I deal something with partial in columns.yaml with my this particular field ? Do you think so ?

Comment: Instead of `valueFrom: street_number` use this: 
`select: 'concat(street_number, '' '', address)'`

Comment: @Meysam I have solved . Check below.

Comment: Additionally, I am almost done with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756590/octobercms-plugin-show-all-the-validations-at-once  , can you check once and help me on this if possible. We are so close on this hence tell you. Issue is, everything works fine, but I am unable to see validation messages with line breaks. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is logic involved here you might just wanna use a custom column type as detailed here https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#custom-column-types. I wouldn't wanna put too much logic inside the yaml file.

*EDIT*

The OP has added some example code to show exactly what I mentioned above in his comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846371/5045612).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have followed your link and added my answer how I made it work. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Guys,

I have come up with with a solution thanks to a nice [suggestion link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825816/6829420) by [Pratyush Pundir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045612/pratyush-pundir) above. Here is what I have done to achieve this.

Updated below chunk of code in **columns.yaml** file.

```
columns:
    property_id:
        label: Property
        type: property_details
        searchable: true
        sortable: false
        relation: Property
```

Added `type: property_details` here.

Opened and updated my **Plugin.php** file and added below lines.

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Homeopenintegration;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;


use technobrave\Properties\Models\Property as Property;


class Plugin extends PluginBase
{


    public function registerListColumnTypes()
        {

            return [
                // A local method, i.e $this->evalUppercaseListColumn()
                'property_details' => [$this, 'evalPropertyDetailsListColumn'],        
            ];
        }


    public function evalPropertyDetailsListColumn($value, $column, $record)
    {
        $current_property = Property::where('id', $record->property_id)->first();
        return $current_property->lot;

    }
}
```

Thanks for efforts and help.